# for $n$ an integer, why is $n^0=1$ ??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity, exponentiation, exponential-function, absolute-value

This is so going to cost me....

I was wondering why for any integer $n$: $n^0 =1$.

Perhaps It's because $n$ is a *round* number and if $m$ is a non negative integer, also round then:
$$n^m = 1 \cdot n^m=1 \cdot \underbrace{n \cdot n \cdots n}_\text{m times}$$
So maybe if we set $m=0$ then:
$$n^m = n^0 = 1 \cdot n^0= 1 \cdot \underbrace{n \cdot n \cdots n}_\text{0 times} = 1$$
Maybe that is because an integer multiplied by it self $0$ times is really doing nothing.

Wait so maybe $0$ multipled by $0$, $0$ times....? $$0^0 = 1 \cdot 0^0 = 1 \cdot \underbrace{0 \cdot 0 \cdots 0}_\text{0 times} = 1 \space\space??$$

$QED.$

If someone could prove to me (I'm trying) that $|x|^{|x|}$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$... Because we already know $lim_{x\to0}|x|^{|x|}=1$..

Comment: *WAKE UP* people. There is no indeterminacy about $0^0$, and there's no need for more than 1 line of equalities to show it. (BTW It's not just so easy to show, It's also backed up by all the Math professors who teach me, with all their confidence)

Comment: If you consider the function $g\colon (0,\infty)\times [0,\infty);\; g(x,y) = x^y$, then there is indeterminacy about $0^0$, since $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} g(x,y)$ does not exist. If you restrict to integer exponents, that problem doesn't arise, but for arbitrary exponents, it isn't cut and dried.

Comment: All your maths professors are mistaken. Yes, $|x|^{|x|}$ tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to $0$, but (for example) $0^x$ tends to $0$. So $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: @TonyK Perhaps they are.. By the way I did not mean to say that the limit I mentioned at the end of my question is enough. But I think one can show that $|x|^{|x|}$ is continuous at an arbitrary real number $x$, without assuming anything about $0^0$. This, coupled with the limit, would mean $0^0=1$, or else we abandon the definition of continuity.. Is this all wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's all wrong. Although $|x|^{|x|}$ is continuous at $x=0$, $x^y$ (as a function of two variables) is not continuous at $(0,0)$, even if we restrict it to non-negative values of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 5):

We can see that $\frac{a^n}{a^m} = a^{n-m}$. So if $n = m$, then we get $\frac{a^n}{a^n} = 1 = a^{n-n} = a^0$.

Of course this intuition fails in explaining what $0^0$ is.

Comment: Indeed this fails.. :(

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind saying "if you multiply nothing you get $1$" is called the [empty product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product), which comes up often in discrete math and abstract algebra.  A similar argument, for example, motivates the definition that $0!$ should be $1$.

This is one justification among [several](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) that $0^0$ should be defined as $1$.

Alternatively, for the case of a positive $n$: if you believe that $n^{a+b} = n^{a}n^b$ and that $n^{-m} = 1/n^m$, then certainly we should have
$$
n^0 = n^{1-1} = n^1n^{-1} = n/n = 1
$$
so if $n$ is non-zero, we should certainly have $n^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation of $n^0$ is perfectly fine.
For $0^0$ we can look at it in 2 diffrent ways:
1) any number to the power 0 is 1 so $0^0$ should be 1
2) 0 to any power is just zero multiplied by itself some times so it should be 0

The fact that diffrent ways to evaluate this give diffrent results makes this undifined, so $0^0$ is not equal to anything

edit: you can see this anayticly:
1) the function $y=x^0$ approaches 1 if we let x approach 0 from the right.
2) the function $y=0^x$ approaches 0 if we let x approach 0 from the right.

Comment: It is not multiplied by it self at all.

Comment: @Jens It is common to define $0^0$ to be $1$ for reasons explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero).  This convention is not, however, universal.

Comment: It is very uncommon to define $0^0$. People did it historicaly, but in mathmatics, algebra-precalculus, now, this is undefined and the equation $0^0=1$ is wrong.

Comment: Who said 2) is continuous?

Comment: I should have said if we aproach it from the right, I will edit

Comment: It is not "very uncommon" to define $0^0$. In a situation where only integer exponents are considered, that is extremely common.

Comment: Yes but I answered in the context of the question tags.

Answer (score 0):

*a^n* is *a* multiplied by itself *n* number of times. When n is negative, it's *1 / a* multiplied by itself *n* number of times. So if *a^1* is a by itself and *a^-1* is 1 / a, when you multiply them together to "add" the exponents to equal zero, you get *a / a* which = 1, even when *a* is 0

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious to look at but it follows from the following;

If we multiply a number raised to a power by the same number raised to another power we can add the powers to find the answer, for example

$2^2\cdot2^3=2^{(2+3)}=2^5$

$4 \times 8 = 32$

If we divide a number raised to a power by the same number raised to another power we can subtract the powers to find the answer, for example

$\frac{3^6}{3^4}=3^{(6-4)}=3^2$

$\frac{729}{81}=9$

We know that if we divide a number by itself we get 1 so

$\frac{a^3}{a^3}=a^{(3-3)}=a^0=1$

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the limit definition as well. As long as a limit is continuous on both sides then it is true.

What happens if we approach it from the positive side? Well, let's take a constant, say 10, to help us see. $10^1$ = 10. That's easy. $10^{1/10}$ is just $\sqrt[10]{10}$, or What number do you raise to the 10th power to get to 10? The answer is 1.2589... Let's try $10^{1/100}$, or $\sqrt[100]{10}$. What number do you raise to the 100th power to get to 10? The answer is 1.023... Let's try $10^{1/10000}$, or $\sqrt[10000]{10}$. What number do you raise to the 10000th power to get to 10? The answer is 1.0000... etc. So we're sure about the positive side. But what about the negative side? Let's figure it out.

$10^{-1}= 1/10.$ Ok. Let's keep going. $10^{-1/10} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[10]{10}}$, which just so happens to equal to 0.79... Let's skip right to the good stuff. $10^{-1/1000} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[1000]{10}}$. This is about .9977... so let's try $10^{-1/1000000} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[1000000]{10}}$ which is about 0.999997. You get the point. Therefore, the limit as x approaches 0 for all $x^0$ where x is not equal to 0 is 1.