# $|x|^{|x|}$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: continuity, exponentiation, exponential-function, absolute-value

I'm trying to show this now my self, but still no go. There isn't really a concrete *attempt*
 that I can show..

Help?

Comment: You can't do this until you define what the function's value at $x=0$ is. $0^0$ isn't defined. For the function to be continuous, you need this to be equal to $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}x^x$ (so this limit must exist).

Comment: @MPW this limit is $1$, is it not?

Comment: Indeed it is, but that's for you to show. Now you need to argue that the function is continuous everywhere else and you are done. @tetori 's answer pretty much suggests why that's the case.

Comment: @MPW you mean everywhere, not everywhere *else*. Yes?

Comment: @MPW this question is directly linked to another "question": http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699760/for-n-an-integer-why-is-n0-1

Comment: i.e, I'm not looking to define $0^0$. I'm looking to *derive* $0^0$

Comment: No, if you define $f(0)$ as the limit I mention, that *makes* $f$ continuous at $0$. You aren't defining $0^0$ when you do this. You are defining $f$ at zero because you can't uses the $x^x$ rule since it doesn't make sense at $x=0$.

Comment: @MPW the answer below suggests It's continuous for an arbitrary real number, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $|x|^{|x|}=\exp(f(x))$ where
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 
|x|\log |x| &\text{if }x\neq 0\\
0 & \text{if }x=0
\end{cases}
$$

Show that $f$ is continuous.